# Замена входного значения на иное

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, коллекции, xmlparser

при парсинге получается значение из ячейки Идентификатор.

```
UnreliableType = member.find('1').find('2').find('3').find('4').find('Идентификатор').text
```

Оно имеет всего два значение 1 или 2. После оно добавляется в массив disc.

```
disc.append(UnreliableType)
```

Необходимо, чтобы при получении 1 значение менялось на 2 и наоборот.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: 1) не называйте переменные с большой буквы -- так классы называются в питоне (поэтому в редакторе UnreliableType и выделился) 2) в питоне не используется верблюжья нотация, с учетом 1) получится: `UnreliableType` -> `unreliable_type` 3) Вам достаточно условие через `if` добавить, можно даже в одну строку: `disc.append('1' if unreliable_type == '2' else '2')`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Чтобы вопрос не висел без ответа, добавил его. Отметьте его, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте условие:

```
if unreliable_type == '2':
    disc.append('1')
else:
    disc.append('2')
```

В одну строку:

```
disc.append('1' if unreliable_type == '2' else '2')
```